# Como funciona expressão regular com duplo range?

Tags: regex

Eu estou estudando regex e tive uma dúvida ao lidar com o operador range (`-`).

Eu entendo que um range como `[a-z]` significa "todo o alfabeto em letras minúsculas" e que um range como `[^A-R]`seria algo como "todas as letras maiúsculas que não estejam entre A e R" (não estou muito seguro sobre esta interpretação).

Mas o que significa uma expressão com duplo range do tipo `[^A-RU-Z]`?

Comment: Quando a [lista](https://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html) é introduzida por `^`, ela se torna uma [lista negada](https://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista-negada.html). Para seu caso de exemplo, você está simplesmente modificando o escopo de uma lista `A-Z` filtrando os caracteres que estão inclusos no *range* `A-R` e `U-Z` - assim preservando os caracteres maiúsculos `S` e `T`. Exemplo rudimentar no  *regex101.com* [1](https://regex101.com/r/MVpkGA/1) e [2](https://regex101.com/r/MVpkGA/2).

Comment: hum ... então é equivalente a `[ST]`?

Comment: Não, nesse caso ela estaria abrangendo todos os caracteres (de qualquer tipo) que não correspondem ao padrão que você especificou na lista negada - incluindo os `S` e `T`.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado. Se quiser, use seu comentário como resposta, eu dou aceite

Comment: Vale lembrar que um range não se restringe a letras, vc pode usar qualquer caractere, então `[!-;]` e `[最-]` são ranges válidos (esta última funciona se a engine tiver o suporte adequado a Unicode, o que varia conforme a linguagem/ferramenta). E no fim - as respostas já explicaram em detalhes, mas de forma resumida - um range é apenas uma forma de "abreviar" um conjunto de caracteres, para não ter que digitar um a um, então o fato de ter 2 ou mais ranges na mesma classe não tem nada de especial :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Classe de caracteres

Quando você usa as notações de classe de caracteres — as notações entre colchetes (`[]`) — você está dizendo que: *capture um caractere que esteja dentro desse conjunto de caracteres*.

Quando você usa o `-`, você está definindo uma *faixa* de caracteres, ou seja, um *range*. Ele acaba servindo como uma "abreviatura" para um conjunto de caracteres que estão em sequência. Por exemplo:

```js
let regex1 = /[A-F]/;
// se torna o mesmo que
let regex2 = /[ABCDEF]/;

// Aqui é testado se todos os caracteres
// da lista atendem ao regex

// true
console.log(['B', 'E', 'D'].every((char) => regex1.exec(char)));
// true
console.log(['B', 'E', 'D'].every((char) => regex2.exec(char)));
```

Ou seja, em ambos os *regexes*, você pede que: *capture um caractere que esteja na faixa/no conjunto de caracteres de `A` a `F` (maiúsculos)*.

---

Porém, note que *"caractere"* está no **singular**, na frase.

Por que? Porque essa notação de classe de caracteres sozinha, só irá capturar *1 caractere*.

Para capturar mais de 1 caractere, você tem que agora utilizar uma das notações de "captura múltipla", que aliás são várias. Mas, um exemplo seria:

```js
// irá capturar toda a string
console.log(/[A-F]+/.exec('BED'));
```

Ou seja: *capture **1, ou mais**, caractere(s) que esteja na faixa de `A` a `F`*.

Outro exemplo:

```js
let regex3 = /[A-F]{2,3}/

// captura 'AB'
console.log(regex3.exec('GHIABJ'));
// captura 'DEF'
console.log(regex3.exec('KLDEFMN'));
```

Ou seja: *capture de (**no mínimo**) 2 a (**no máximo**) 3 caracteres que estejam na faixa de `A` a `F`*.

#### Classe de caracteres com negação

A partir daí, nós podemos também utilizar a notação de negação. Ou seja, ao invés de *"capture um caractere que **esteja** no conjunto [...]"*, podemos também fazer *"capture um caractere que **não esteja** no conjunto [...]"*.

Para estabelecer essa negação, nós colocamos o símbolo `^` após o colchete de abertura (`[`) da notação.

Portanto, utilizando o exemplo acima, podemos ver o que acontece agora:

```js
let regex4 = /[^A-F]{2,3}/

// captura 'GHI'
console.log(regex4.exec('GHIABJ'));
// captura 'KL'
console.log(regex4.exec('KLDEFMN'));
```

Ou seja, agora a *regex* diz que: *capture de 2 a 3 caracteres que **não estejam** na faixa de `A` a `F`*.

Portanto, nós podemos agora inverter a captura de caracteres para que **não esteja** em uma certa faixa de caracteres.

#### Junção de faixas (*ranges*)

E enfim, chegamos ao ponto do qual se trata a questão!

Como vimos anteriormente, o hífen (`-`) serve para, de certa forma, "abreviar" uma certa faixa/sequência de caracteres. Portanto, se quisermos juntar um *range* com outro, basta adicionar o novo *range* ao conjunto — ou seja, dentro dos colchetes (`[]`) — dessa forma:

```
[A-DW-Z]
```

Pois isso seria o mesmo que:

```
[ABCDWXYZ]
```

Que também é válido! Vejamos:

```js
let regex6 = /[ABCDWXYZ]+/;
let regex7 = /[A-DW-Z]+/;

// captura 'ABCD'
console.log(regex6.exec('EFABCDGH'));
console.log(regex7.exec('EFABCDGH'));

// captura 'WXYZ'
console.log(regex6.exec('STWXYZUV'));
console.log(regex7.exec('STWXYZUV'));
```

Portanto, quando você usa a regex `[^A-RU-Z]`, você está dizendo: *capture um caractere que **não esteja** na faixa de `A` a `R` e de `U` a `Z`*.

Ou seja, conforme citei acima, seria o mesmo que:

```
[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRUVWXYZ]
```

#### Cuidado!

Uma das primeiras coisas que deve-se notar, no entanto, é que os "motores de *regex*" podem mudar de comportamento, de linguagem pra linguagem. Nesse caso, eu utilizei JavaScript. Mas, em outras linguagens, algumas dessas coisas podem agir de forma diferente (da que se encontra no JavaScript).

Uma segunda coisa que deve-se notar é que as *regexes*, normalmente, são *case sensitive* (sensíveis ao estado da letra, se maiúscula ou minúscula). Portanto, conforme coloquei no primeiro exemplo, todos esses *regexes* só irão se aplicar aos caracteres que estão da mesma forma que você os definiu. Assim sendo, conforme dito na outra resposta, *strings* como:

```js
"eSTe TexTo Será capTurado"
```

Passariam pela *regex*, caso ela fosse `[^A-RU-Z]+`, por exemplo.

Portanto, algumas linguagens oferecem o meio de tornar a *regex* "insensível ao *case* da letra". No JavaScript, por exemplo, seria adicionar a *flag* `i` ao final da *regex*:

```js
// captura somente 'ST'
console.log(/[^A-RU-Z]+/i.exec("eSTe TexTo não Será capTurado"));
```

Da mesma forma, outra coisa que pode-se notar é que, pelo meio que fiz, só será capturada a primeira sequência de caracteres que estão dentro da faixa! Ou seja:

```js
let matches1 = Array.from('ACMN STWZ'.match(/[ABCDWXYZ]+/));
let matches2 = Array.from('ACMN STWZ'.match(/[A-DW-Z]+/));

// em ambos os casos, só irá capturar o `AC`

console.log(matches1);
console.log(matches2);
```

Para que ela capture todas as ocorrências que possam existir, no JavaScript, eu coloco a *flag* `g` ao final da *regex*:

```js
matches1 = Array.from('ACMN STWZ'.match(/[ABCDWXYZ]+/g));
matches2 = Array.from('ACMN STWZ'.match(/[A-DW-Z]+/g));

// captura tanto o `AC` como o `WZ`
console.log(matches1);
console.log(matches2);
```

Inclusive, você pode ver [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486951/125486), a diferença entre usar uma *regex* global com o método `String.prototype.match` (conforme coloquei acima) e com o método `String.prototype.matchAll`.

#### Conclusão

Portanto, vemos que existem tantas coisas que devem ser levadas em conta na hora de montar uma *regex* — entre elas, a própria linguagem onde você irá utilizá-la — que se eu fosse tentar cobrir aqui, deixaria a resposta bem [mais] extensa!

---

Alguns conteúdos sobre *regex*:

- [Expressões Regulares - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [Regex: Um guia prático para expressões regulares](https://medium.com/@alexandreservian/regex-um-guia-pratico-para-express%C3%B5es-regulares-1ac5fa4dd39f)

Answer (score 6):

Quando a [lista](https://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html) é introduzida por `^`, ela se torna uma [lista negada](https://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista-negada.html). Para seu caso de exemplo, você está simplesmente modificando o escopo de uma lista `A-Z` filtrando os caracteres que estão inclusos no *range* `A-R` e `U-Z`.

Note nos exemplos a seguir que a expressão regular estará resultando nos caracteres maiúsculos `S` e `T` (que não se enquadram no *range* definido) bem como todos os demais tipos de caracteres (minúsculos, números, caracteres com acento, pontuação, ...):

1. **AbSUc/1**
   Os caracteres resultantes seriam `b`, `S`, `c`, `/` e `1`
   [Exemplo 1](https://regex101.com/r/MVpkGA/4)
2. **ÚvaxT.2**
   Os caracteres resultantes seriam todos os caracteres, incluindo o `Ú` (`U` acentuado é considerado um caractere distinto)
   [Exemplo 2](https://regex101.com/r/MVpkGA/5)