# Quais as diferenças entre os métodos String.prototype.match e String.prototype.matchAll?

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Historicamente, o JavaScript conta com o método `String.prototype.match` para realizar, por exemplo, buscas em strings através de um padrão via expressão regular.

No entanto, a partir do ECMAScript 2020, strings também possuem o método `String.prototype.matchAll`.

- O que motivou a introdução do `matchAll`?
- Quais são as diferenças e, de modo geral, como devo escolher um em relação ao outro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma diferença é que [`String.prototype.match` retorna um array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) e [`String.prototype.matchAll` retorna um iterador](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Return_value), mas tem vários outros detalhes a se atentar.

## `String.prototype.match`

Quando a regex não tem a [*flag*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) `g`, o método `String.prototype.match` retorna um array contendo somente a primeira ocorrência, e mais algumas informações relacionadas (como por exemplo os [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). Mas quando tem a *flag* `g`, o resultado contém somente os *matches*, sem informações adicionais:

```js
let s = 'a1 b2 c3 d4';

console.log('---sem flag "g"---');
// sem flag g, pega somente a primeira ocorrência, com informações adicionais
let result = s.match(/[a-z](\d)/);
for (let i in result) console.log(`${i}=${result[i]}`);

console.log('---com flag "g"---');
// com flag g, pega todas as ocorrências, sem informações adicionais
result = s.match(/[a-z](\d)/g);
for (let i in result) console.log(`${i}=${result[i]}`);
```

A regex é `[a-z](\d)` (uma letra seguida de um número, sendo que o número está entre parênteses, o que forma um grupo de captura).

Sem a *flag* `g`, o array retornado tem:

- na primeira posição, a primeira ocorrência (`a1`)
- nas demais posições, os grupos de captura (no caso, só temos um grupo, contendo o dígito `1`)
- a propriedade `index` contendo o índice onde o *match* foi encontrado (`a1` está no índice zero da string)
- a propriedade `input` contendo uma cópia da string inteira
- a propriedade `groups`, que contém somente os [grupos nomeados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383646/112052) (por isso o grupo que contém o dígito não está ali).

Mas se usarmos a *flag* `g`, o array contém somente os trechos que deram *match* (somente `a1`, `b2`, etc), sem as informações adicionais (nada de grupos, `index`, etc).

---

## `String.prototype.matchAll`

Antes de existir o método `String.prototype.matchAll`, a única forma de obter as informações adicionais para todas as ocorrências era usando o [método `RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
let s = 'a1 b2 c3 d4';
let r = /[a-z](\d)/g;
let match;
while (match = r.exec(s)) {
    console.log('----');
    for (let i in match) console.log(`${i}=${match[i]}`);
}
```

Repare que agora cada chamada de `RegExp.prototype.exec` retorna um array contendo o *match* e as informações adicionais.

Mas com `String.prototype.matchAll` fica um pouco mais simples fazer a mesma coisa:

```js
let s = 'a1 b2 c3 d4';
for (const match of s.matchAll(/[a-z](\d)/g)) {
    console.log('----');
    for (let i in match) console.log(`${i}=${match[i]}`);
}
```

E como `String.prototype.matchAll` retorna um iterador, dá para usá-lo com `for..of` (como no exemplo acima), com *spread* para criar um array com os resultados (`[...s.matchAll(/[a-z](\d)/g)]`), etc.

---

Um detalhe é que com `String.prototype.matchAll`, **a regex deve obrigatoriamente ter a *flag* `g`, caso contrário dará erro** (e uma curiosidade é que se você usar `RegExp.prototype.exec` sem a *flag* `g`, [ele entra em *loop* infinito](https://ideone.com/EWBSoH), já que `exec` faz a busca a partir do `lastIndex`, mas sem a *flag* `g` este valor sempre é zero, então neste caso ela sempre vai encontrar um *match*).

Aliás, este é outro detalhe: `RegExp.prototype.exec` atualiza o [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) da regex, então cada chamada passa a procurar a partir desta posição. Mas `String.prototype.matchAll` não mexe no `lastIndex`:

```js
let s = 'a1 b2 c3 d4';
let r = /[a-z](\d)/g;
let match;
while (match = r.exec(s)) {
    console.log(r.lastIndex); // o índice vai sendo atualizado conforme encontra os matches
}

let r2 = /[a-z](\d)/g;
for (const m of s.matchAll(r2)) {
    console.log(r2.lastIndex); // não muda, é sempre zero
}
```

---

Por fim, outra diferença entre eles é o suporte dos *browsers*: `String.prototype.match` e `RegExp.prototype.exec` são compatíveis com versões mais antigas (inclusive o IE 4!), enquanto `String.prototype.matchAll` só foi introduzido em versões mais novas (e não funciona no IE). Consulte as tabelas de compatibilidade [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#browser_compatibility), [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#browser_compatibility) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#browser_compatibility).