# JavaScript regex horários

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo uma expressão regular para verificar o seguinte padrão:

> 2M1-2M2-6M1-6M2 Física 2

Horários (separados por `-`) + espaço + nome da matéria.

Onde o primeiro digito significa (2-segunda | 3-terça | 4-quarta ...) e o segundo e terceiro dígito respeitam uma tabela de horários, onde:

- M1 -> Manha das 07h30 as 08h20
- M2 -> Manha das 08h20 as 09h10
- T1 -> Tarde das 13h00 as 13h50
- N4 -> Noite das 21h20 as 22h10

E assim por diante ...

O problema é que, na minha regex, não consegui uma forma de eliminar o ultimo `-`.
Na forma que fiz, ela esta aceitando horários do tipo:

```
2M5-2N5- Física 2
```

Sendo que deveria aceitar: `2M5-2N5 Física 2`. (sem `-` no final)

O padrão da regra pode aceitar somente um horário: `5T1 Física 2`, ou vários horários `1M2-1M3-1M4-5T1-5T2-5T3 Física 2`.

Regex:

```
/^(([2-6]{1})([N]{1}[1-5]{1}|[MT]{1}[1-6]{1})([-]{1})){1,}([' ']){1}(.{1,})$/gim
```

Alguma ideia de como posso solucionar o problema do `-` no final?

Não sei se tem como referenciar grupo no regex, porque eu não sei quantas vezes vai repetir os horários, só sei que, se terminar os horários e tiver um espaço não pode ter um `-`. Mas não consegui passar isso em código.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você focou exageradamente em regex e nos separadores de conteúdo que acabou perdendo o foco do seu problema que é interpretar o texto.

Na verdade o problema nem precisa ser resolvido com regex, o método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) já bastaria. Eu decidi usar o regex apenas para mostrar que o uso duma ferramenta computacional não deve ser o objetivo mas sim um facilitador para alcançar um resultado.

O algoritmo é trivial, receber uma entrada num formato compacto específico e a quebrar em informação menores e as tornar humanamente legíveis.
Para isso criei um array `diasDaSemana` que contém descrição literal dos dias da semana em português.
Também criei a função `periodo()` que funciona de acordo com a tabela apresentada na pergunta.

Separei o nome da matéria da informação dos horários de aula que chamei de `turnos`.
Então nesses `turnos` extraí as informações com [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) ignorando os separadores assim podendo trabalha individualmente cada unidade de informação.

```js
const entrada = "2M1-2M2-6M1-6M2 Física 2";

const diasDaSemana = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];

function periodo(p) {
  return (p == "M1") ? "de manhã das 07:30am as 08:20am" :
    (p == "M2") ? "de manhã das 08:20am as 09:10am" :
    (p == "T1") ? "a tarde das 01:00pm as 01:50pm" :
    (p == "N1") ? "a noite das 09:20pm as 09:50pm" :
    "na madrugada dos mortos";
}

let [turnos, ...matéria] = entrada.split(" ");     //Separa nome da matéria das informações de turnos.
matéria = matéria.join(" ");                       //Contorna a limitação do método split JS.

turnos = turnos.match(/(\d[MTN]\d)/gim);               //Cria a lista de turnos ignorando informações desnecessárias. 

console.log(`Horário das aulas de ${matéria}:`);
for (let t of turnos) {
  let texto = `${diasDaSemana[parseInt(t[0])-1]} ${periodo(t.slice(1))}`;
  console.log(texto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa de regex. **Se** o formato é esse e você já validou (ou se "tem certeza" que sempre recebe uma string válida), [bastaria separar as partes com `split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e depois obter os três primeiros caracteres de cada uma das partes.

```js
const diasDaSemana = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
const periodos = {
    "M1" : "manhã das 07:30 às 08:20",
    "M2" : "manhã das 08:20 às 09:10",
    "T1" : "tarde das 13:00 às 13:50",
    "N4" : "noite das 21:20 às 22:10"
    // coloque aqui todas as opções
};

const entrada = "2M1-2M2-6T1-6N4 Física 2";
const i = entrada.indexOf(' '); // índice do primeiro espaço
const horarios = entrada.slice(0, i); // tudo até o primeiro espaço
const materia = entrada.slice(i + 1); // tudo depois do primeiro espaço
console.log(`Horários de ${materia}`);
// obtém os horários (separa por hífen)
for (const sigla of entrada.split('-')) {
    // pega o primeiro dígito e obtém o respectivo dia da semana
    const dia = diasDaSemana[parseInt(sigla[0]) - 1];
    // pega o código do período (ou uma mensagem padrão, caso não haja horário correspondente)
    const periodo = periodos[sigla.slice(1, 3)] || 'Não há horário cadastrado';
    console.log(`${dia} - ${periodo}`);
}
```

Primeiro eu separo os códigos de horário e o nome da matéria (basicamente, um é "tudo antes do primeiro espaço", o outro é "tudo depois do primeiro espaço").

Depois faço outro `split` por hífen, obtendo assim os códigos dos horários. Aí é só "fatiar" cada código: o primeiro caractere (obtido com `sigla[0]`) é transformado em número com `parseInt`, e subtraio 1 para obter o respectivo índice no array `diasDaSemana` (fiz assim porque o primeiro índice é zero, por isso tem que subtrair 1).

Depois eu pego o restante do código (`sigla.slice(1, 3)`, que pega do segundo caractere até o terceiro) e verifico se existe no objeto `periodos` (ali você cadastra todas as opções de códigos e respectivos horários). Repare que há também uma verificação caso o código não exista (não sei se cairá nesse caso, verifique se faz sentido para você).

---

#### Mas se quiser mesmo usar regex...

A solução acima eu acho bem mais simples e é o que eu usaria, mas se quer mesmo usar regex, vamos lá...

A primeira coisa é retirar esse monte de `{1}`, pois é redundante e desnecessário. Por padrão, `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)` (e para repetir algo uma ou mais vezes, pode usar o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` em vez de `{1,}`).

A ideia é similar (primeiro separa o nome da matéria, depois percorre os códigos):

```js
const diasDaSemana = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"];
const periodos = {
    "M1" : "manhã das 07:30 às 08:20",
    "M2" : "manhã das 08:20 às 09:10",
    "T1" : "tarde das 13:00 às 13:50",
    "N4" : "noite das 21:20 às 22:10"
    // coloque aqui todas as opções
};

const entrada = "2M1-2M2-6T1-6N4 Física 2";
const i = entrada.indexOf(' ');
console.log(`Horários de ${entrada.slice(i + 1)}`);
const regex = /(\d)([MNT]\d)(-|$)/g;
for (const match of entrada.slice(0, i).matchAll(regex)) {
    const dia = diasDaSemana[parseInt(match[1]) - 1];
    const periodo = periodos[match[2]] || 'Não há horário cadastrado';
    console.log(`${dia} - ${periodo}`);
}
```

A regex é `(\d)([MNT]\d)(-|$)`. [Cada par de parênteses forma um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que você pode obter depois. O primeiro par de parênteses (e portanto o grupo 1) contém somente `\d` (um dígito, que no caso é o dia da semana).

Depois, no segundo grupo, temos `[MNT]`, que indica "a letra `M`, ou a letra `N`, ou a letra `T`" (apenas uma delas - e aqui você pode colocar mais opções, caso tenha), seguido de um dígito.

E há ainda um terceiro grupo, que verifica se tem um hífen ou o marcador `$`, que [indica o final da string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Lembre-se que antes separamos a string original em duas partes: os códigos e o nome da matéria, então estou buscando os *matches* apenas na parte que tem os códigos, por isso não haverá nada depois do último (daí a necessidade de verificar um hífen **ou** o final da string).

A seguir, usamos `matchAll` (que [exige que a regex tenha a *flag* `g`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486951/quais-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-os-m%c3%a9todos-string-prototype-match-e-string-prototype-m/486963#486963)), para percorrer os *matches*. E para cada *match*, pegamos os grupos (`match[1]` pega o primeiro grupo, que é o dia da semana, `match[2]` pega o segundo grupo, que é código do horário).

---

Você também usou as *flags* `i` e `m`, mas não acho que são necessárias. O `i` habilita o modo *case insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas), mas no seu caso parece que os códigos sempre têm letras maiúsculas, então não parece fazer sentido usar o `i`. E o `m` habilita o modo *multiline*, no qual os marcadores `^` e `$` (que indicam o início e fim da string) passam a considerar também o início e fim de uma linha. Mas no seu caso, como a string está toda em uma linha, o `m` não faz diferença.

Outro detalhe é que, como a quantidade de códigos varia, não tem como obtê-los separadamente em um mesmo *match*. Por exemplo:

```js
const match = "2M1-2M2-6M1-6M2 Física 2".match(/^\d[MNT]\d(-\d[MNT]\d)* (.+)$/);
console.log(match[1]); // -6M2
```

Eu coloquei o trecho `(-\d[MNT]\d)` (hífen, dígito, letra, dígito) para se repetir zero ou mais vezes (indicado pelo `*`), mas repare que o grupo só é preenchido com a última ocorrência encontrada (no caso, `-6M2`). Então não tem como obter os resultados intermediários separadamente com apenas um *match* (dá para obter tudo junto, mas aí você teria que separá-los usando um dos métodos acima).