# Regex para buscar por um CNPJ contido em uma string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Como consigo identificar e pegar apenas o CNPJ contido em uma string?
Exemplo:

```
const conteudo = "Esse é um conteúdo que possui um CNPJ de número 73.727.057/0001-60. Esse é apenas um exemplo".
const capturaCNPJ = conteudo.search("^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}$");
```

Tentei usar um regex com a função `search`, mas não funciona da forma como eu esperava. Acredito que exista alguma função de busca no JavaScript que retorne apenas a parte do conteúdo desejado.

Comment: Isso não responde. São perguntas parecidas, mas distintas. Eu não preciso validar o CNPJ, tanto é que já tenho um regex pra isso. Eu preciso é realizar a filtragem dele, o que é bem diferente do conteúdo do link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) que `search` retorna o **índice** da string que corresponde ao início da primeira ocorrência do *match*, caso exista.

Como você quer o conteúdo e não o índice, use `match` em vez de `search`. Mas tem outros poréns.

Ao usar uma string em vez da regex, você deve escapar a barra invertida e escrevê-la como `\\`. Mas para simplificar, bastaria usar uma regex literal, delimitada por barras - ou seja, `/expressão/` em vez de `"expressão"`. E assim não precisa escapar a barra invertida.

Outro detalhe é que você usou os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string. Ou seja, a regex só encontraria um *match* se a string tivesse apenas o CNPJ e nada mais. Então no seu caso você tem que remover esses marcadores.

Por fim, [`match` retorna um array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) contendo várias informações (explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486951/112052)), e o CNPJ estará na primeira posição dele. Portanto ficaria assim:

```js
const conteudo = "Esse é um conteúdo que possui um CNPJ de número 73.727.057/0001-60. Esse é apenas um exemplo";
const capturaCNPJ = conteudo.match(/\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}/)[0];

console.log(capturaCNPJ);
```

Repare que o hífen não precisa de escape.

Um detalhe é que isso vai pegar apenas o primeiro CNPJ que encontrar. Mas se quiser todos, adicione a *flag* `g`, que o retorno será um array com todas as ocorrências:

```js
const conteudo = "Esse é um conteúdo que possui um CNPJ de número 73.727.057/0001-60. E outro: 12.345.678/0001-90 e outro 98.765.432/0002-47 etc";
// flag "g" - vai no final, depois da última barra
const todos = conteudo.match(/\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}/g); 
// retorna um array contendo todos que encontrar 
console.log(todos);
```

Repare no `g` depois da última barra, esta *flag* muda o comportamento da regex e faz com que ela retorne todas as ocorrências.

---

E para garantir que não vai pegar algo que por acaso se pareça com um CNPJ (por exemplo, se tiver algo como `173.727.057/0001-60123`, que tem dígitos a mais no início e fim), você pode trocar a regex para `/\b\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}\b/`. O atalho `\b` faz com que só pegue o CNPJ caso não tenha nenhum caracetere alfanumérico antes e depois (ver mais detalhes sobre o `\b` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/112052)). Exemplo:

```js
const conteudo = "CNPJ 73.727.057/0001-60. Não é: 123.123.123/0001-60123. Esse é: 12.345.678/0001-90.";
const todos = conteudo.match(/\b\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}\b/g);
// só pega o primeiro e o último
console.log(todos);
// sem o "\b", pega também o do meio, que não é um CNPJ pois tem dígitos a mais
console.log(conteudo.match(/\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}/g));
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisa, muito obrigado. Suas explicações foram excelentes.

Comment: Sugestão: `\b\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}\b`, em caso de valores digitados incorretamente (se é que vai ocorrer)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu até ia colocar ontem, mas acabei esquecendo. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!